# JavaScript: Problem with a ActiveX-Object and the apply()-Function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, apply

i have an ActiveX Object (Master) and would like to invoke functions dynamically on it. To do this i use the apply() Function. But sadly the InternetExplorer tells me something along the lines of: "This Object doesn't support this Method". Can someone give me a hint what i could do?

(To test this you also could use a small flash object as Master and call "doSomething" instead of my specific "Initialize".)

```
function invoke(object, fnName, args)
{
  return object[fnName].apply(object, args);
}

function test_it()
{
  try{
    Master = window.document["Master"];
  }
  catch(e){alert(e);}
  var param = [1,"VC2"]; 
  var ret = invoke(Master, "Initialize", param);
  alert("got: "+ret);
}
```

For comparsion, this is the apply() Function in action:

```
function Obj()
{
  this.msg = function(a, b, c)
  {
      alert("msg: \n a: "+a+"\n b: "+b+"\n c: "+c);
      return "hi";
  }
    return this;
}


function invoke(object, fnName, args)
{
  return object[fnName].apply(object, args);
}

function test_it()
{
  var obj = new Obj();
  var ret = invoke(obj, "msg", [1, 2, 3]);
  alert("got: "+ret);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks kangax for your time and your extensive explanation!
Sadly i could not get it working this way(it works for the alertbox though)
But it led me to the idea to use a proxy-class. It's not the most elegant way because i have to provide every function from my object i want to use but it works AND it doesn't involve eval()!

```
function proxy(obj)
{
    this.obj = obj;

    this.Initialize = function(a, b)
    {
        return obj.Initialize(a, b);
    }   
}

function test_it()
{
    var myMaster = new proxy(window.document["Master"]);    
    var ret = myMaster["Initialize"].apply(myMaster, [1, "VC2"]);
    alert(ret);
}
```

Again, thanks for your time!

Comment: @hobotron I think that if you try it with my edit to Kangax's answer, it should work!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with some of the host objects (i.e. any non-native objects) in IE (and not only IE) is that they don't inherit from `Function.prototype` (and often neither from top level `Object.prototype`). Some host objects that **might look like functions** actually have nothing to do with functions except that they can be called. The fact that these objects don't inherit from `Function.prototype` means that they fail to be identified as functions with `instanceof` operator; that their constructor is not referencing `Function`; and that they lack all of the `Function.prototype.*` methods, such as `call` or `apply`. Even their internal [[Class]] property might not be that of "Function", as it is with any native object (note that [[Class]] can be inferred from the result of `Object.prototype.toString` value).

This is actually expected, since **host objects are not required** to implement many things that native objects do (as per ECMA-262, 3rd ed.). It is perfectly allowed for a host object to, say, throw error on method invocation (e.g. `hostObject.hostMethod()`); or when passing it as an operand to standard operators like `delete` (e.g. `delete hostObject.hostMethod`). As you can see, it is also OK for callable host objects to NOT inherit from native `Function.prototype`.

Such unpredictable (yet perfectly compliant) behavior is actually one of the main reasons why **host objects augmentation is recommended against**.

But back to your `call` problem : )

The thing about these "tricky" IE host objects is that they often implement internal [[Call]] method, and it is possible to invoke `call` and `apply` on them, although **not directly**.

Here's a pattern to emulate `apply` invocation on an object that doesn't have it:

```
function f(){ return arguments };
Function.prototype.apply.call(f, null, [1,2,3]); // [1,2,3]
```

`null` can be replaced with whatever context object should be called in, of course.

And an example of `apply` invocation on host object that has no `call`:

```
// should work in IE6, even though `alert` has no `call` there
Function.prototype.call.call(alert, window, 'test');
```

**Applying it to your code**

```
// Calls Master.initialize borrowing from Function.prototype
Function.prototype.apply.call(Master.initialize, Master, [1,"VC2"]);
```

Comment: This is the real answer. Host object methods do not support `Function.prototype.apply` but you can always borrow it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and I solved it by compiling a thunk function at run-time to unroll the right number of arguments (similar to the previous solution, but without the restriction that the ActiveX object handle has to be in a global variable).

```
varArgsThunkFunctionsCache = [];

function getVarArgsThunkFunction(arrayLength) {
  var fn = varArgsThunkFunctionsCache[arrayLength];
  if (!fn) {
    var functionCode = 'return o[m](';
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
      if (i != 0) {
        functionCode += ','
      }
      functionCode += 'a[' + i + ']';
    }
    functionCode += ')';
    fn = new Function('o', 'm', 'a', functionCode);
    varArgsThunkFunctionsCache[arrayLength] = fn;
  }
  return fn;
};


function invoke(object, methodName, args) {
  var fn = getVarArgsThunkFunction(args.length);
  return fn(object, methodName, args);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently IE's JS engine doesn't see ActiveX functions as JavaScript Function objects on which you can call `apply()`. How about just doing an `eval()` -- although ugly, it seems to be your only option.

```
function invoke(objectName, fnName, args) {
    return eval(objectName + "." + fnName + "(" + args + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd mention that if you use the `eval` method as Ates Goral said you need to be careful of string arguments in your array as they will be considered variable names, eg

```
function invoke(objectName, fnName, args) {
    return eval(objectName + "." + fnName + "(" + args + ")");
}
invoke("Master", "Initialize", [1, "VC1"]);
```

the `eval` will be passed the line

```
Master.Initialize(1,VC1)
```

which will throw an error if VC1 is not a defined variable. It might be best to "unroll" the array name instead of passing literals:

```
function UnrollArray(arrayname, length) {
    var s = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        s += arrayname + "[" + i + "],";
    }
    return s.substring(0, s.length - 1); //remove the trailing comma
}
```

so invoke becomes

```
function invoke(objectName, fnName, args) {
    var unrolledarray = UnrollArray("args", args.length);
    return eval(objectName + "." + fnName + "(" + unrolledarray + ");");
}
invoke("Master", "Initialize", [1, "VC1"]);
```

the `eval` will then be passed

```
Master.Initialize(args[0],args[1]);
```